# When is it Best to Test Coefficients for Unity?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, econometrics

Suppose:

```
ŷ = β0 + β1*x + ε
```

Of course we can use wald tests for nulls like: H0: β1 = 0. That is clearly great for testing statistical significance. However, testing the coefficients for other values can be really useful too.

For clarity, here are 2 text book examples (Wooldridge 2004):

```
log(campus_crime) = β0 + β1*log(enrollment_rate) + ε
```

[image]

Wooldridge points out that if the wald test finds that β1>1, that would suggest that larger campuses are more affected by crime (all else constant).

```
log(sales) = β0 + β1*log(marketing) + ε
```

Similarly, here Wooldridge points out that if a wald of β<1, then the budget of marketing for that company is not necessarily justified.

**My Question:** The post title is self explanatory. But let me add, this is not a technical question, it's more of a critical thinking question. I also am not looking for anything industry specific, any industry/specification is acceptable. I'll take any answer that illustrates some of the underlying principles of when wald tests for coefficients = 1 or < 1 or > 1 are most useful.

Thank you

Comment: If need be, I can reiterate or add more specification if there is confusion in the community. I made a few changes in the post to articulate the question better.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but in your/Woolridge's first example a $ß_1 > 0$ would also suggest larger campuses are more affected by crime (all else constant). Only a $ß_1 <= 0$ would suggest otherwise. IMO the second example is better fitting to your question: where a $ß_1 > 1$ would suggest the budget for marketing brings about larger sales returns (but only when they are on the same scale, i.e. both measured as x times 1000€ or other amount of other currency).

Comment: Yea, good point. I think he was saying if ß1>1 then it would have more crime not just in absolute terms, but also in relative terms. The visual shows how Wooldridge was comparing them.